# Why is it easier to write a server side script in PHP vs C (with libraries for all web related functions)?

Tags: php, c

If PHP is written in C, what exactly would be the difference between writing a server side script in PHP vs C, esp if I was using a web framework for C that could handle mysql connections, SESSIONS, etc.?

Comment: You need to explain your question more.  What sort of differences do you mean?  In terms of writing it?  Implementation?  Your question isn't specific enough.

Comment: Life forms on earth are made with Carbon,hydrogen etc. It doesn't mean that we are Carbon,Hydrogen etc :)

Comment: @AndyLester, I mean in terms of writing it.  What makes it easier?  I haven't written anything in C before so I'm just wondering why it wouldn't be just as easy to write a server side script in C, with the help of libraries.

Answer (score 3):

That is like asking why you wouldn't write a server side script in assembly.  PHP is a higher level language designed to make writing those scripts easier.  The difference would be the time and effort required to get the job done... And to make it run on a web server.

Examples:

- memory management
- built in globals like $_REQUEST, $_SERVER, etc
- built in session mechanics
- built in handling of HTTP headers (reading and writing for responses)

Comment: can you give some basic examples of why it would be easier?

Answer (score 1):

PHP programs uses more memory and run slower, but has a well-suited, large library.
Writing C is relatively tedious, and will take a longer time, but they will be fast and efficient. How much faster and efficient, depends on the program.

If your PHP program doesn't have a performance bottleneck due to a piece of PHP code (because it's interpreted code), I can suggest you to go on with PHP.

Alternatively, by the way, you may also want to try [Go](http://golang.org).

Answer (score 1):

You've asked an extremely general question, so here's an extremely general answer

PHP - Derived from perl, used mainly as a web programming language. Generally interpreted, although some projects such as HipHop compile it. It has many features designed specifically for generating dynamic web content. Other things are available as library.

C - Derived from Algol 68. Used to program everything you can imagine, at least at one point. Many large systems (such as the Linux Kernel) are written entirely in c. C has very few features in the language, even basic string processing requires the use of the C standard libraries.

One unexpected similarity between C and some versions of PHP is the single, global namespace.

You can write a website purely in C. It has been done before, and could be done again. However, there is very little reason to do so. At most, it would be worth writing a small section of your website (or even just a few performance critical operations) in C and the remainder in an interpreted language like PHP, Python, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can absolutely use C as your server side application. **That being said, please note that PHP is a high level language which will result in better managed code and shorter developing times.**

Google for instance, uses C++ for speed critical systems in their infrastructure. However, if you are not aiming for something that is performance hungry, probably you are better off with a high level language like PHP.

**PHP is written in C.** This means that, if you want to write a server side application in C, you have to do all the extra work yourself. (ie. memory management, session mechanics, etc...)

Comment: I've only ever written in PHP, so I am unaware of what would make it cumbersome to write a server side script in C or C++.  Can you provide some basic examples?

Comment: C is called the mother of languages. It is very low level compared to other practical and high level languages (line PHP, C#, Phyton, ...). PHP is written in C. This means that you have to write most of the functionality of PHP itself in C, after which you can have your server side do work.

Comment: Can PHP's functionality not be written into a framework for C?

Comment: Of course it can be written. **PHP is written in C.** So, you can re-write it if you really want to :)

Comment: Lol, I suppose my question is really, why hasn't it already been written in C?  If the speed is faster, and PHP is written in C, why bother writing a PHP engine instead of just writing a C framework?